# Go to href after jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code is the JS I'm running to create an accordion style sidemenu. The category class is nested within the group class, which is nested within the section class. How do I alter this JS to go to the href after the slide up or slide down event? I need the href from the html.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var activeElement = $('#cssmenu').find('.active');
        activeElement.parentsUntil(".section").show();

        $('.section > a').click(function () {
            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('.group-list')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('.group-list')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('.group-list:visible').slideUp('normal');
                $('.category-list:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('.group > a').click(function (e) {
            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('.category-list')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('.category-list')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('.category-list:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        });
        $('.category > a').click(function () {
            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('.category-list')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Move your `window.location` so it's next to the slide within the if statement?

Comment: huh... that worked... pretty dumb problem... i wasn't getting to the window.location line due to the returns... *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `slideUp` and `slideDown` methods accept a callback:

http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

For example:

```
$('.group > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal', function() {
        window.location.href = href;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) (And the slideDown) event takes a callback function that executes after the animation is complete. Then you can just use scrollIntoView() or whatever you want.